# When to use div id or div classes through an entire website

Tags: html, css

Sorry for this basic over asked question but I feel I have something to add.

I know id's are for elements which are only used once and classes are for elements which use it multiple times. But does this refer to a single page or the site as a whole?

i.e If I were using a wrapper called main-wrapper which is only used once in the page but on every page of the website would this be an id or a class? I've been making them classes throughout this project and am curious if I need to go back and change it all.

Comment: IDs have to be unique in the context of a document. Every page is a new document (unless it contains dynamically loaded content from another page). So yes, you can re-use IDs throughout your site, like you can use `#header` for all your site headers.

Comment: Id's are unique to the page, not the site. Whether you use id's or classes is open to much debate/opinion. There is no clear 'right way' IMO. Both have benefits

Comment: id must be unique, and yes you can use it in different page just no on same page.

Comment: It refer elements in document. If you call your css in all page, yes rigth its refer to whole site.

Comment: The advantage of ID is that it is indexed (because it is unique), so the browsers can access it very quickly. Think of a hash table. Classes on the other hand, returns one or more matching elements, which means selectors that work with classes are slower than those working with IDs.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response guys :) ...If you're bored check out my other question which seems to be dormant atm :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID's and classes are not just about uniqueness and duplications. There is something called Specificity in CSS, so if you read more on specificity, it will say that ID declarations have more specificity score than class rules, thus, it is recommended to use classes wherever you can in your CSS and leave ID's for JavaScript actions.

Also, lets be clear here, CSS has nothing to do with ID duplication nor does HTML. It's JavaScript where you will find issues if you duplicate the ID in your HTML(DOM). So technically you can use duplicate ID's as they are just identifiers for that element(though, HTML validation will yell out an error), but it does cause an issue when you start using those ID's in JavaScript. *(Now am not saying that you should use duplicate ID's but just clarifying the basics.)*

Talking more over specificity,

```
#something {
  color: red;
}

.something {
  color: green;
}

<div class="something" id="something">This will be red and not green</div>
```

So, the more you make use of ID's, the more specific your CSS gets and at certain stage, you need to write even more specific rules to override the previous ones thus creating more messy CSS.

---

Base rule, use tag selectors wherever you can, atleast to set defaults or resetting those elements, use classes over ID's, leave ID's if you want initiate a particular EVENT or ACTION via JavaScript, for example, a click event on a button. Using ID's in your HTML helps JavaScript process faster as it will stop looking for another element beyond your first matched element.

Comment: " it is recommended to use classes wherever you can in your CSS and leave ID's for JavaScript actions"

Recommended by who? There are good arguments to use ID's for CSS too as it creates more succinct and targeted (and therefore performant) CSS.

Comment: @LDJ Well, I wouldn't recommend doing so, because I see no good reason to use ID's over classes, as it is more specific, I've seen people using it for wrapper elements and so, but again, classes can be used instead. I've never seen bootstrap and other frameworks using ids...

Comment: Thanks for the juicy info, very interesting. I guess I don't have to sift through my code and replace the classes after all. Would it be a bother for you to check out my other unanswered question? I can't move on before fixing it :).

Comment: @MarcusPorter Read your previous question, are you looking for something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/u0n5xL32/

Comment: Not quite. my example is closer. I just want a 50px margin to the right of the grey box if the viewports width is small enough. I'm finding it hard to explain. If your busy 1 answered question could be enough for today :)

Comment: @MarcusPorter yea sorry, lil busy :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks for the info regardless, I'm sure many users will find this interesting.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases things are referred to on a **per page** or **per document** basis.

No ID should be repeated on a **single page** of a web site. But it's is fine to use the same ID on *every* page of a site. So you can have a primary div with id="main_container" and use that on each page of your site. But it should only appear once on each page.

A "class" is designed to be used multiple times on each page or on an as-needed basis.